# Tracking which UIAlert button is clicked to change UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I'm a complete beginner and looking to learn how to start coding to build my own apps.
I've been messing around with the classic "Hello World" design and trying to improve on it based on the limited knowledge i have managed to gather in the past week but i've got stuck and hope someone can help me out!

So far I have a UITextField for the user to enter their name, a label to display their name and a button to update the display. To help understand UIAlertViews better I have also included a Alert if the name entered is Chris (or chris) and another alert if the name entered is not Chris. All this is functioning fine so far.

I'm looking to track what button is pressed on my incorrectName UIAlertView and then update my UILabel to say "Chris" if they click the "I Want to be Called Chris" button. I have build another app similar to this before from a tutorial and I have copied across the code which i thought should function the same but it doesnt seem to work.

Here is my .m file so far

```
#import "Solo1ViewController.h"

@interface Solo1ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Solo1ViewController

@synthesize setMessage;
@synthesize userName;

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle=([alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"I Want To Be Called Chris!"])
    {setMessage.text=@"Chris";}
}

-(IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender
{
    setMessage.text=userName.text;

    if ([userName.text isEqual:@"Chris"] || [userName.text isEqual:@"chris"])
        {
        UIAlertView *correctName;
        correctName = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@":)" message:@"Great Name!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Bye Fellow Chris" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [correctName show];
        }
    else
        {
            UIAlertView *incorrectName;
            incorrectName=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@":(" message:@"Chris is a Better Name" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"No, Thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"I Want To Be Called Chris!", nil];
            [incorrectName show];
        }
}

-(IBAction)removeKeyboard:(id)sender{
    [userName resignFirstResponder];
}
```

To me it seems as though this should work but I guess I'm probably missing something glaringly obvious or i'm doing it totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set the alert view's delegate to `self`!  Right now you have the delegate set as `nil`.

Example:

```
incorrectName=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@":(" message:@"Chris is a Better Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No, Thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"I Want To Be Called Chris!", nil];
```

Comment: Just to expand slightly, this is what a delegate does; it steps in and handles certain duties/responsibilities which have been delegated for external handling.  In this case, responding to buttons touches.  Other classes, most famously `UITableView`, delegate other functions to external handlers/responders/sources.

Comment: Thanks very much both of you! Fixed my problem and it makes a lot more sense now